# How to get my wlan adapter up and running

Tags: debian, wifi

I just got ZyXEL NWD2105, a small wlan usb adapter that i found on [this list](http://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb) of supported usb adapters.

I've already done

- sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant, I'm already at the newest version
- sudo apt-get install firmware-ralink
- sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

My config looks like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

auto wlan0
iface wlan inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid <my ssid>
        wpa-psk <aes key>
#        address 192.168.1.11
#        netmask 255.255.255.0
#        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

- sudo ifup wlan0, IT STATES: Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0.

So, does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DOH!

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan inet dhcp
```

should have been

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```